# Jar execution with double-click fails (Eclipse fine), because of code change

Tags: java

If i access my images using the following code, then the whole project runs on eclipse and executes as Jar:

```
BufferedImage myPicture;
BufferedImage myPicture2;


try {
        myPicture= ImageIO.read(new File("button1.jpg"));
        myPicture2 = ImageIO.read(new File("button2.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, if i replace the above with the following code, then the whole project runs on eclipse BUT doesn't execute as a Jar, it doesn't respond with double-click :

```
    myPictureurl = getClass().getResource("button1.jpg");
    myPictureurl2 = getClass().getResource("button2.png");
    icon = new ImageIcon(myPictureurl);
    icon2 = new ImageIcon(myPictureurl2);

    // icon to bufferedimage
    myPicture = new BufferedImage(
    icon.getIconWidth(),
    icon.getIconHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    //
    myPicture2 = new BufferedImage(
    icon2.getIconWidth(),
    icon2.getIconHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    //
    Graphics gg = myPicture.createGraphics();
    icon.paintIcon(this, gg, 0,0);
    gg.dispose();

    Graphics g2 = myPicture2.createGraphics();
    icon2.paintIcon(this, g2, 0,0);
    g2.dispose();
```

Note: After acquiring the BufferedImage, i use it to draw a CustomButton:

```
/**
 * paints the CustomButton
 */
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(myPicture, 0, 0, 200, 25, this);

    if (pressed) {
        g.setColor(getBackground().darker().darker());
        g.drawImage(myPicture2, 0, 0, 200, 25, this);

    } else {
        g.setColor(getBackground());

    }
```

Why does the last code inhibits the jar execution?

Actually , 
1) i'm getting a NullPointerException at this line:
     `icon = new ImageIcon(myPictureurl);`
My images are placed inside the main application folder, src folder, and bin folder:
"button1.png"
"button2.png"

The second code block i posted, works fine for other image resources in my project, although.

2) and a FileNotFoundException for my "config.properties" load method: 
    `try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }`

**UPDATE:**

For no apparent reason, one trial jar loads the images fine, however i cannot make another same one.

Comment: run it via terminal/command line. Most likely your jar is running, but  you are getting an exception when trying to load the resources. Are the images properly bundled into the jar?

Comment: Is it a runnable jar? Check the `manifest.mf` file and see if `Main-Class` has the correct value.

Comment: Rp: Yes it's Runnable, Main Class is fine

Comment: Nic, I run it via terminal, results are above, thanks. I can assume that images are bundled fine, because with some other images everything works fine. Both of these resource groups are handled the same way.